# Assignment of a store to an existing datagrid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

How do I assign a store to an existing view?

I'm dynamically creating a Controller with its associated views. One of its views is a gridpanel, and I want to set and/or change the store of such gridpanel once it's already instantiated from the recently instantiated Controller.

I couldn't find a setStore() or similar method in the gridpanel component or any of its ancestor classes.

Is this feasible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because store is not assigned to a controller. Each store is basically static object inside the Ext.StoreManager.

When you specify something like

```
stores: [ 'MyStore' ]
```

in the controller definition you just indicating to the ExtJs parser that you need to load that store class in memory and will probably will be using it.

When you need to use the store inside controller just get it with `Ext.getStore('MyStore')` or `this.getStore('MyStore')`

Update: use `bindStore()` method

Comment: right. emaringolo,  you are mixing controllers and views concepts. there are some nice guides that clarify this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/mvc_pt1 (read all 3 parts)

Comment: You're right, what I meant was to assign the newly instantiated store to the existing dataview.

Comment: Please update your question with some code and what exactly you need to achieve. It's not clear right now.

Comment: I entirely rephrased my question.